# I have two separate functions one collects form text the other toggles display of an image. I'm unable to pull values from the other variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, dom, global-variables

Note: I'm not a javascript expert so please be kind. I continue to get a Null value from a variable that I believe is triggered from a DOM event. I have two functions. One looks at form text whether it is present, if not it pulls from another existing variable so it should never be empty/null. However when I try to pull these variable results into another function it returns Null. I'm trying to have a form where the user enters a filename (picture name) and the script inserts the rest of the string around this filename. Allowing the user to not have to enter a full url path and especially not html code. This works if I put the variables in manually as text strings, I'm just not able to get anything other than null from that variable inside this function.

I thought this was due possibly to the DOM event but I tried everything I could find on here with no success. I even tried making the variable global which didn't help. I'm trying to concatenate text before and after this other variable data. If I put these other variables in as string text it works fine, but whenever I try to pull the other variable outside of the function I get Null. I've mascaraed my java at this point. I've been coming back to this the past few days trying different thing with no success. Thank you.

```
    // This checks for radio toggle and writes html(var string) if on
function output_headshot() {

var text1 = "<td border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><br><img src=\"https://url/Headshots/";
var text2 = headshot_path;
var text3 = "\" width=\"154\" height=\"154\"></td>";
var headshot_html = text1 + text2 + text3;

$(".headshot_element").show();
  $(".headshot_element").html(headshot_html);
  // Monitor logo option to hide/show
  $(".input_headshot input[type=radio]").on("change", function(){
    if(document.getElementById('headshot_show').checked) {      
      $(".headshot_element").show();
      $(".headshot_element").html(wpe_headshot_html);
    } else if(document.getElementById('headshot_hide').checked) {
      $(".headshot_element").hide();
      $(".headshot_element").html('');
    }
    updateHtmlSigRaw()
  });
}
output_headshot();

// This looks at form contents, if empty pulls from another static variable employee.headshot_location
// This will display the text string on HTML using this: <span class="output_headshot_location"></span>

$(".input_headshot_location input").on("change keyup paste", function(){
  var headshot_location = $(this).val();

  if(headshot_location) {
    $("span.output_headshot_location").html(headshot_location)
  } else {
    $("span.output_headshot_location").html(employee.headshot_location);
  }
  updateHtmlSigRaw()
});
```

EDIT: Added for context

```
// Place raw HTML of each version into appropriate containers
function updateHtmlSigRaw() {
  get_html_signature_full_visual = document.getElementById("signature-full-visual").innerHTML;
  get_html_signature_horizontal_visual = document.getElementById("signature-horizontal-visual").innerHTML;
  $("#signature-full-html textarea").text(get_html_signature_full_visual);
  $("#signature-horizontal-html textarea").text(get_html_signature_horizontal_visual);
}
```

This is starting normal variables.

```
// Start Normal variables
var employee = {
    headshot_location: "TimC-Rounded-SQ-SM.png"
}
```

The following is how I'm placing in HTML for the image to toggle off an on.

```
<td height="237" valign="middle" style="padding:0px 10px 0px 0;">
<div class="headshot_element" onClick="document.location = 'https://url'" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
```

Next is the form for input.

```
<div class="input_headshot_location form-group">
<label>Headshot Location</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="headshot_location" placeholder="Enter Full Filename">
</div>
```

Expecting to pull string from variable to add/concatenate to other static string variables to insert html into page using  Span class or Div class.

Comment: Hi @gjames! Currently it is difficult to understand where your problem comes from, mainly because there isn't enough context information around the JS. For example: What is `wpe_headshot_html` and where does it come from? Or: What does `updateHtmlSigRaw()` do? Please be so kind to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi @David . I edited my original post to add the updateHtmlSigRaw function as well as the HTML I'm using for input and output. Thank you.